# How do I pass a value to a Controller's constructor?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

So, in effort to unit test our controllers I am trying to slim down our controllers and make them more testable. We use a Service/Reposistory pattern and one issue we have is multiple instantiations of our service layer. Each method in the controller instantiates a new instance of the service layer. To correct this I would like to instantiate a single time in the Controller's constructor.

Here is an example of our typical Controller method:

```
public class GroupController : ControllerBase // ControllerBase is derived from System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public ActionResult EditGroup(int groupId)
    {
        EditGroupViewModel model = new EditGroupViewModel();
        using (var service = new AccountServices(this.User)) // this.User is an instance of IPrincipal Controller.User            {
            Group group = service.GetGroupWithRoles(groupId);
            // some code to map Group to EditGroupViewModel
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Any method that uses AccountServices must instantiate a new instance of the class as shown above. Ideally, the AccountServices would be instantiated a single time in the Controller's constructor. However, I'm unsure how to do this.

Here is what I tried:

```
    private readonly AccountServices _service;

    public GroupController(IPrincipal user)
    {
        _service = new AccountServices(user);
    }
```

However, when placing a breakpoint on the constructor I see that IPrinicipal user remains null.I think my biggest obstacle is the fact that AccountServices requires an IPrincipal Controller.User to be instantiated.  How can I instantiate AccounServices a single time in the constructor so that all of the Controller's methods can use the instance?

Comment: Possible solution is to use dependency injection container, line `AutoFac` and declare your dependencies as interfaces like `IAccountServices` . after that you can register that as Single instance. `builder.Register<AccountServices>().As<IAccountServices>().SingleInstance();`

Comment: Using DI container that supports per-request instantiation (probably all widely used containers have that support) is likely better solution... (not really answer to your question so).

Comment: MVC doesn't know it should call your controller with the IPrincipal. You should get the principal from your controller context in the constructor. But look into using a DI container, it makes your life easier.

Comment: I recommend to use Unity instead of AutoFac because ASP.NET Core 1 has Unity built in.

Comment: what would you recommend for mocking? Moq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dependency injection and a custom factory for that. Here's a [site](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/asp-net-mvc-tip-dependency-injection-with-structuremap) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think my biggest obstacle will be the fact that AccountServices requires an IPrincipal Controller.User

Comment: Not sure about your particular situation but you can get a user identity from HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity if you are using integrated windows security or HttpContext.Current.User.Identity if using Forms authentication

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I believe we are using Forms authentication. Could I get the user identity when the constructor is called?