# Getting request parameters in controllers constructor or something like that

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, controller

I want to add a required field to all of my methods in a controller but i have no idea how should i  achieve that.I dont want to add field to all of my methods cause i feel its not the right way to do it.Here is an example :

```
public IActionResult GetLastLegals()
{
        return Ok(_service.GetLastInformationEnumerable((int)InformationTypeId.Legals));
}

public IActionResult GetNews([FromQuery] FilterLastInformationDto filterLastInformation)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    return Ok(_service.GetLastInformationWithFilter(filterLastInformation, (int) InformationTypeId.News));
}
```

I want to add an int field to these methods and i dont want to pass it as methods input argument cause then i should change all of my methods signature.I know i can do it like

```
[HttpGet("Legals")]
public IActionResult GetLastLegals([FromQuery] RequiredField)
{
    return Ok(_service.GetLastInformationEnumerable((int)InformationTypeId.Legals));
}
```

but i feel like there is a better way to that like getting it in controller's constructor or adding it to route????
I would appreciate your ideas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a value to a Controller's constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106221/how-do-i-pass-a-value-to-a-controllers-constructor)

Comment: @Carrivas it can be used for dependency injection like services and etc. but not for parameters i guess.Thanks for your comment anyway.